# Reconhecimento de arquivo XML no Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse

Estou utilizando uma linguagem privada, derivada do XML, com extensão .fml.

Gostaria de fazer com que o eclipse reconhecesse o código como se fosse XML, para facilitar a visualização.

Tem alguma maneira de alterar a configuração do Eclipse para que ele reconheça essa extensão .fml como XML?

Comment: Não sei se isso aqui ajuda, eu passo longe de eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-13.htm

Comment: Deu certo amigo! era isso mesmo, obrigado!